# Excluding multiple filetypes with find

Tags: bash, find

I have a folder with 20k plus Images and most gui filemanagers (like dolphin) aren't able to manage this amount of data.

So I decided to use the bash instead. My problem is the following:

- most of the files are `*.IMG` or  `*.LBL` files
- I am not interested in those files. I look for the others
- with `find . -type f -not -name "*.LBL"` I am able to see all files instead of the `*.LBL`
- with `find . -type f -not -name "*.IMG"` I am able to see all files instead of the `*.IMG`
- both is not very helpful, since it still fills my terminal
- either combining both seems not to work:

```
find . -type f -not -name "*.LBL" -o -not -name "*.IMG"
```

What is the correct way to see the files inside a folder excluding multiple filesuffixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group conditions, I think -o -not isn't working as expected. Try this:

```
find . -type f -not \( -name "*.LBL" -o -name "*.IMG" \)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash's [extended pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) (Might have to be turned on in a script with `shopt -s extglob`; usually enabled by default in an interactive shell):

```sh
printf "%s\n" !(*.LBL|*.IMG)
```

Comment: worked also, but since ```find``` is much faster than your solution (and also a little bit closer to my question) I accept the other awnser. But nice to now, that something like this is also working.

Comment: If speed is so important in this task, you can try a Rust find as [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd)

Comment: I'm surprised they're not around the same. Maybe because of the sorting of the filenames that the glob does.

Comment: Speed is not that important, but it was noticable between both solutions.